# Calculating kinetic energy without Mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy

Is it possible to calculate the kinetic energy of a body if its velocity is given its direction is vertical and its hight is 0 at moment t=0

Comment: So there's no way to do it?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Since kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and mass bears no relation to velocity, there are clearly objects with the same velocity that have different kinetic energies. What about that is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The question has been edited (to yet a more obscure form). Here I am replying to the original formulation:

> Is it possible to calculate the kinetic energy of a body if only its
>   speed is given?

Yes ... if the speed is $c$ (the speed of light).

In the case of massless particles (think: photon) in the vacuum, what you'd call kinetic energy is given by:
$$E=p c\,,$$
where $p$ is the momentum. (We can relate the momentum to the frequency, $\nu$, *via* $p=h\nu/c$).

If the speed is not $c$, then you need more information in order to calculate the kinetic energy.